# Longer LK4 Pro moving to corner mid print

Tags: extruder

My printer is the Longer LK4 Pro, and I just got it 2 days ago. When I started to print some objects, on a certain layer, the printer would stop and move to the far right corner of my bed. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Is it instructed to do so? Have you checked the G-code file? Do you know what layer? What layer is it printing, e.g. a very small one, is it happening with all prints? Please add more context to the question, otherwise it will be difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the slicer is using a minimum cooling time per layer and the corner is set as its home coordinates.  In the settings of your printer you can set the home coordinates and in the slicer you can reduce/remove the time between layers.